# Redis store location of users strategy

Tags: redis

I want to store users locations(long,lat) in redis database. In my initial idea the keys will be users ids. I need 2 functionality: **set location** , **get all locations**. How should I perform it, or in which structure should I store it to easy and fast access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [`SETS`](http://redis.io/topics/data-types#sets) is an good idea (**if need location uniqueness**):

- UserId as key.
- [`SADD`](http://redis.io/commands/sadd) for **set location** (require O(N) where N is the number of members to be added)
- [`SMEMBERS`](http://redis.io/commands/smembers) for **get all locations** feature.
- Hold long, lat as some delimiter separated string or serialized value (json for example).

PHP sample

```
$location = json_encode(array('long' => '...', 'lat' => '...'));
$redis->sAdd('locations:' . $userId, $location);
...
$redis->sAdd('locations:' . $userId, $location2);
...
$redis->sAdd('locations:' . $userId, $location2);
...
$userLocations = $redis->sMembers('locations:' . $userId);
```

You did not say this, but **if do not need uniqueness** of locations the [`LISTS`](http://redis.io/topics/data-types#lists) would be best choise:

- [`RPUSH`](http://redis.io/commands/rpush) for **set location** (require O(1))
- [LRANGE](http://redis.io/commands/lrange) for **get all locations** feature.
- Key and value format like in [`SETS`](http://redis.io/topics/data-types#sets) case.

PHP sample

```
$location = json_encode(array('long' => '...', 'lat' => '...'));
$redis->rPush('locations:' . $userId, $location);
...
$redis->rPush('locations:' . $userId, $location2);
...
$redis->rPush('locations:' . $userId, $location2);
...
$userLocations = $redis->lRange('locations:' . $userId, 0, -1);
```

If user has only one location [`HASH`](http://redis.io/commands#hash) would be best choise:

- One key for all users, for example `locations`
- [`HSET`](http://redis.io/commands/hset) where field is your userId and value is serialized data

PHP sample

```
$location = json_encode(array('long' => '...', 'lat' => '...'));
$redis->hSet('locations', $userId, $location);
...
$userLocation = json_decode($redis->hGet('locations', $userId));
```

Comment: I have many users each has it's own id and long lat. Can I just serialize json object of my user and store it in redis set?

Comment: How can I store it as in map, ID => JSON Object?

Comment: I`l update my answer about this case. HASH data type should be your choise.